# How to use buildout to create localized version of my project?

Tags: python, sqlite, buildout

I am trying to create a localized version of my project.

I started from the following:

```
mkdir my
cd my
wget http://svn.zope.org/*checkout*/zc.buildout/trunk/bootstrap/bootstrap.py
```

After the last command I get the following message:

> Warning: wildcards not supported in
>   HTTP.
>   --08:42:17--  http://svn.zope.org/*checkout*/zc.buildout/trunk/bootstrap/bootstrap.py
>              => `bootstrap.py' Resolving svn.zope.org... 74.84.203.155
>   Connecting to
>   svn.zope.org|74.84.203.155|:80...
>   connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting
>   response... 200 OK Length: unspecified
>   [text/x-python]
>
> ```
> [ <=>                                                                                                                                    ] 2,572         --.--K/s
> ```
>
> 08:42:17 (122.64 MB/s) -
>   `bootstrap.py' saved [2572]

You can see there a warning message. I do not know what it means and if I should wary about it. Any way, I tried to continue.

```
python bootstrap.py init
vi buildout.cfg
```

In the buildout.cfg I put the following:

```
[buildout]
parts = sqlite 

[sqlite]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = pysqlite
interpreter = mypython
```

And then I execute:

```
./bin/buildout
```

At that stage I have problems:

> Getting distribution for
>   'zc.recipe.egg'. Got zc.recipe.egg
>   1.2.2. Installing sqlite. Getting distribution for 'pysqlite'. In file
>   included from src/module.c:24:
>   src/connection.h:33:21: error:
>   sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
>   In file included from src/module.c:24:
>   src/connection.h:38: error: expected
>   specifier-qualifier-list before
>   ‘sqlite3’ In file included from
>   src/module.c:25: src/statement.h:37:
>   error: expected
>   specifier-qualifier-list before
>   ‘sqlite3’ src/module.c: In function
>   ‘module_complete’: src/module.c:99:
>   warning: implicit declaration of
>   function ‘sqlite3_complete’
>   src/module.c: At top level:
>   src/module.c:265: error: ‘SQLITE_OK’
>   undeclared here (not in a function)
>   src/module.c:266: error: ‘SQLITE_DENY’
>   undeclared here (not in a function)
>   src/module.c:267: error:
>   ‘SQLITE_IGNORE’ undeclared here (not
>   in a function) src/module.c:268:
>   error: ‘SQLITE_CREATE_INDEX’
>   undeclared here (not in a function)
>   src/module.c:269: error:
>   ‘SQLITE_CREATE_TABLE’ undeclared here
>   (not in a function) src/module.c:270:
>   error: ‘SQLITE_CREATE_TEMP_INDEX’
>   undeclared here (not in a function)
>   src/module.c:271: error:
>   ‘SQLITE_CREATE_TEMP_TABLE’ undeclared
>   here (not in a function)
>   src/module.c:272: error:
>   ‘SQLITE_CREATE_TEMP_TRIGGER’
>   undeclared here (not in a function)
>   src/module.c:273: error:
>   ‘SQLITE_CREATE_TEMP_VIEW’ undeclared
>   here (not in a function)
>   src/module.c:274: error:
>   ‘SQLITE_CREATE_TRIGGER’ undeclared
>   here (not in a function)
>   src/module.c:275: error:
>   ‘SQLITE_CREATE_VIEW’ undeclared here
>   (not in a function) src/module.c:276:
>   error: ‘SQLITE_DELETE’ undeclared here
>   (not in a function) src/module.c:277:
>   error: ‘SQLITE_DROP_INDEX’ undeclared
>   here (not in a function)
>   src/module.c:278: error:
>   ‘SQLITE_DROP_TABLE’ undeclared here
>   (not in a function) src/module.c:279:
>   error: ‘SQLITE_DROP_TEMP_INDEX’
>   undeclared here (not in a function)
>   src/module.c:280: error:
>   ‘SQLITE_DROP_TEMP_TABLE’ undeclared
>   here (not in a function)
>   src/module.c:281: error:
>   ‘SQLITE_DROP_TEMP_TRIGGER’ undeclared
>   here (not in a function)
>   src/module.c:282: error:
>   ‘SQLITE_DROP_TEMP_VIEW’ undeclared
>   here (not in a function)
>   src/module.c:283: error:
>   ‘SQLITE_DROP_TRIGGER’ undeclared here
>   (not in a function) src/module.c:284:
>   error: ‘SQLITE_DROP_VIEW’ undeclared
>   here (not in a function)
>   src/module.c:285: error:
>   ‘SQLITE_INSERT’ undeclared here (not
>   in a function) src/module.c:286:
>   error: ‘SQLITE_PRAGMA’ undeclared here
>   (not in a function) src/module.c:287:
>   error: ‘SQLITE_READ’ undeclared here
>   (not in a function) src/module.c:288:
>   error: ‘SQLITE_SELECT’ undeclared here
>   (not in a function) src/module.c:289:
>   error: ‘SQLITE_TRANSACTION’ undeclared
>   here (not in a function)
>   src/module.c:290: error:
>   ‘SQLITE_UPDATE’ undeclared here (not
>   in a function) src/module.c:291:
>   error: ‘SQLITE_ATTACH’ undeclared here
>   (not in a function) src/module.c:292:
>   error: ‘SQLITE_DETACH’ undeclared here
>   (not in a function) src/module.c: In
>   function ‘init_sqlite’:
>   src/module.c:419: warning: implicit
>   declaration of function
>   ‘sqlite3_libversion’ src/module.c:419:
>   warning: passing argument 1 of
>   ‘PyString_FromString’ makes pointer
>   from integer without a cast error:
>   Setup script exited with error:
>   command 'gcc' failed with exit status
>   1 An error occured when trying to
>   install pysqlite 2.5.5.Look above this
>   message for any errors thatwere output
>   by easy_install. While:   Installing
>   sqlite.   Getting distribution for
>   'pysqlite'. Error: Couldn't install:
>   pysqlite 2.5.5

Can anybody tell me, pleas, what these error messages means and how the above problem can be solved?

Answer (score 4):

You need install sqlite develop library.

In ubuntu or debian, run:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have sqlite installed before you start installing the python bindings.